# Converting ndarray to grayscale

Tags: python, image, machine-learning

So i have this ndarray of shape

```
(39000, 64, 64, 3)
```

of

```
dtype=np.uint8
```

and i am trying to convert all 39k images to grayscale in a while loop

```
while(image_index<num_images):
    gray_dataset = np.dot(dataset[image_index,:,:], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
    image_index +=1
```

which is obviously producing trash. Could you guide me to doing it properly?

Comment: `np.sum((dataset[image_index,:,:] / 255.0) * [[[0.299, 0.587, 0.114]]], axis=-1)`?

Comment: it produces one image of shape (64,64)

Comment: So you want to convert all the images at once, or only one at a time (the `image_index`-th one) on each loop iteration? For everything at once: `np.sum((dataset / 255.0) * [[[[0.299, 0.587, 0.114]]]], axis=-1)`

Comment: I'd like only one per iteration, so i have exactly the same shape as input

Comment: Not sure I follow then. If you want one per iteration, shouldn't you expect one 64x64 image as a result? Or do you want to keep the three channels, even if it is grayscale?

Comment: alright i might have messed up a bit, the shape of gray_dataset is expected to be (39000,64,64,3) as i just want to scale every image to grayscale, there could be more efficent way of doing it, the while loop is just my idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert all the images in `dataset` to float point grayscale format, while keeping the three channels, you can just do:

```
# (39000, 64, 64, 1)
gray_dataset_1c = np.sum((dataset / 255.) * [0.299, 0.587, 0.114], axis=-1, keepdims=True)
# (39000, 64, 64, 3)
gray_dataset = np.tile(gray_dataset_1c, (1, 1, 1, 3))
```

Or with `np.dot`:

```
# (39000, 64, 64)
gray_dataset_1c = np.dot((dataset / 255.), [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
# Since Python 3.5 this can be written like this:
gray_dataset_1c = (dataset / 255.) @ [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]
# (39000, 64, 64, 3)
gray_dataset = np.tile(gray_dataset_1c[..., np.newaxis], (1, 1, 1, 3))
```

After a quick benchmark, it seems that `np.dot` is actually significantly faster for this use.

Comment: Thank god there are smart people on this world. But last one question. Which one is theoretically faster? np.sum or np.tile?

Comment: @KingVidfamne The comparison would be between a multiplication followed by `np.sum` and `np.dot`. I guess `np.dot` might be marginally faster, even if only because it's one function call instead of two, but I'd have to run a benchmark (maybe later...)

Comment: No need to, was just asking because my laptop almost died when trying to compute first option with np.sum, but after all everything worked properly, thanks alot!

Comment: @KingVidfamne Just gave it a try and actually `np.dot` is much faster! With `a = np.random.rand(10000, 1000); b = np.random.rand(1000)`, `np.dot(a, b)` takes ~7ms and `np.sum(a * b, axis=1)` ~100ms. I thought `np.dot` was just a convenience function (at least in this use case), but it looks like it has a much more optimized implementation...

Comment: yeah, actually when tried np.dot my laptop wasn't as flooded as before, thank you for your time, appreciate!